# Prevent double entry in MySQL (eg when an insert request is called multiple times rapidly)

Tags: mysql, transactions, duplicates, mariadb, banking

hello I have a question:

I'm making a simple deposit and withdrawal tables on MySQL.

I'm wondering for a way to make a robust withdrawal/deposit entry insertion in preventing double entries (eg, when user do a double withdrawal API request). anybody knows a good way to do it?

I'm thinking of using Table lock, however, this can only be done with MYISAM, and might have a low performance?
another way is to use a unique key, but what can be the unique key for withdrawal entry?

Simple Scenario example:

You have a 1 BTC in a bitcoin exchange site. When you withdraw that 1 BTC into your wallet, the code will create a withdrawal entry of 1 BTC in the withdrawals table.

How to make sure that the code will not create a double withdrawal entry for that 1 BTC?

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE ... amt = amt - $amt WHERE ...;
UPDATE ... amt = amt + $amt WHERE ...;
INSERT INTO transactions ...;
COMMIT;
```

is how InnoDB prevents the classic problem.  Are you referring to another situation?